# Does continuity of joint density function imply continuity of marginal density functions?

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables

We have two continuous random variables $X,Y$ (not neccessarily independent) and we know that their joint density function exists and is continuous. Does it follow that the probability density function of $X$ (and $Y$) also exists and is continous?

Equivalent (?) statement without mentioning r.v. :

- we have continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ such that $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}(x,y)=1$
- is it true that function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0},x\mapsto\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}y$ is well-defined and is continuous?

My attempt:

- I tried to make use of the "integral=1" condition so I tried to bound a $(1-\epsilon)$ fraction of $f$'s area-under-surface in some interval of $y$.
- But it cannot guarantee that area-under-curve for *every* fixed $x$ is also at least $(1-\epsilon)*total\_area$ in this interval of $y$ - which is required in ordered to prove continuousness using definition.

Comment: The density must exist by definition by the way.

Comment: @DanielAdams what about the cantor distribution? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution

Comment: @Bey the OP defines $X$ as a continuous random variable, hence it has a density function by definition.

Comment: @DanielAdams a continuous random variable has a continuous cumulative distribution function by definition, but when the cdf isn't differentiable, pdf doesn't exist. At least it seems so to me.

Comment: @inverse your right. I remembered another definition, must be forgetting though.

Comment: @DanielAdams absolutely continuous will work: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs501/abs.cont.pdf

Comment: @inverse this may be helpful as well — continuity of a function isn’t a strong enough condition to guarantee continuity under integration: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410199/does-integration-preserve-continuity/2410212#2410212

Comment: At least $g$ is lower semi-continuous (Fatou).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g$ is well defined (a.e.) and is a probability density by Tonelli's theorem (and defined everywhere by Fatou's lemma).
I think that this should be a counterexample to continuity (if you eliminate the hypothesis that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, by Daniel Adams' observation).

Let $\varphi:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ a continuous function such that $\varphi(0)=1$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\varphi=1$. Then
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}\phi(x)  & \text{if} & x>0\\
 0 & \text{if} & x\le 0
\end{cases}$$
should be a continuous probability density but $g$ is not continuous